# What was the Line Education Movement?

Tags: short-stories, historical-context, tibetan-language, pema-bhum

["Wink"](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/blink) is a Tibetan short story by Pema Bhum, translated to English by Tenzin Dickie and freely available to read online from Words Without Borders at the above link. It's set in (presumably) Tibet under Chinese rule, at the time of Chairman Mao's death, and the main theme of the story is about the importance, in that society at that time, of showing utmost respect to Mao and his image. In the 2nd part of the story, when Tenpa is talking with his wife Lhamo:

> Putting the bowls in a shoulder bag, she said, “Do we really have to leave in this way? There are so many copies now of *Quotations from Chairman Mao Tse-tung* that a lot of families don’t know what to do with them and throw them in the trash.”
>
> “Whatever people did with *Quotations from Chairman Mao Tse-tung* before the Line Education Movement, do you think that it’s OK to do that now during the Line Education Movement?”
>
> Tenpa asked Lhamo the question but answered it himself in a loud voice, “No, it’s not OK!” He woke Darmar, who was sleeping next to him. The child gave a low cry, and Tenpa stopped talking and put his hand on Darmar. Moving his lips a little, Darmar fell back asleep.

It seems that any disrespect towards the image or writings of Mao is anathema in their society. Assuming that this is a realistic depiction of life in Tibet at that time, **was the "Line Education Movement" also a real thing?** I tried to search for this phrase on the internet but found nothing for the exact quote except this story, and searching without forcing the exact quote led me to pages like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_education) which are irrelevant. Perhaps it was a translation choice made by the translator of this specific story and not the term generally used in English for some real historical movement or event?

Comment: There's also a [bilingual version](https://www.wordswithoutborders.org/article/bilingual/blink) of the same story with side-by-side English and Tibetan versions. Just on the very slim off-chance that someone on this site happens to understand Tibetan ...

Answer (score 1):

The full name appears to be "mass line education," as part of the plan to train the people in communist doctrine. See [Why China's 'mass line' movement is headed for a dead end](https://www.scmp.com/comment/insight-opinion/article/1293928/why-chinas-mass-line-movement-headed-dead-end) by Chang Ping (*South China Morning Post*, 03.08.2018).

Comment: This would improved if you could summarize the source you linked to.